# La aplicacion se detuvo. (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Ya llevo rato desarrollando una app en android studio con java, al principio funcionaba y abria perfectamente en cualquier dispositivo ya sea fisico o emulado.

El problema es que cuando se exporta la apk para probarla en los dispositivos nisiquiera instala y cuando instala no abre en el dispositivo y aparece el tipico mensaje de **La aplicacion se detuvo** sin nisiquiera mostrar la primera actividad, la unica manera de que se abra es que se instale mediante el cable USB desde android studio.

Aqui los dos archivos **build.gradle**.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.aprendecontando"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Si alguien sabe una posible solucion lo agradezco.

Answer (score 0):

Tu Problema es que tu aplicación no está firmada y se instala en modo debug.

Haz lo siguiente :

Build > Generate Signed Apk

Creas una clave que vas a guardar porque la vas a necesitar para firmar todos tus apk.

[Si te sirve márcala como respondida, sino escríbeme al correo osdway@gmail.com]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a lo que comentas, cuando exportas el .APK y tratas de instalarlo este marca error, en este caso hay tres cosas importantes a contemplar.

1. Si tienes instalado un .APK que fue firmado con otro Keystore, no vas a poder instalar el .APK, debes eliminar previamente el que se encuentra instalado.
2. El `versionCode` de la aplicaciòn que deseas actualizar debe ser mayor a el `versionCode` del .APK instalado en el dispositivo.
3. El .APK que puedes usar para instalar y que se encuentra firmado con el Keystore de "Debug" se encuentra dentro de :

   app/build/outputs/apk/debug/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]